# Replace string pattern with a string in linux file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed

I am a newbie to Linux. Need to replace

```
/en/family/bitstream/ambiance-bt
/en/family/zxcvbn/bernhard-fashion
/en/family/qwerty/century-751
/en/family/abcd/century-expanded
/en/family/xyz/charter-bt
/en/fonts/sdfsd/dsfsdfs
```

With

```
/en/family
/en/family
/en/family
/en/family
/en/family
/en/fonts/sdfsd/dsfsdfs
```

using sed or some alternative.

Comment: replacing each one individually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command that given desired result to me is:

```
sed  's/\/en\/family\/\.*.*/FamilyPage/' filename
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this command :

```
sed 's/pattern_to_replace/string_to_insert/' yourfile
```

I don't give you more precise example because I don't understand what you want to replace.

**Edit1, after your first comment :**

```
sed 's@/en/family/.*@FamilyPage@' yourfile
```

Comment: pattern_to_replace is changing after /en/family/****

Comment: @ajay https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/418066

Comment: need to remove end part like "/bitstream/ambiance-bt" however above command only replace starting part and rest remains same

Comment: Above command replace all line startin with /en/family/ and replace it by FamilyPage. You need to keep '.*' to match end of line. According to your example, this command should works sed 's@/en/family.*@/en/family@' yourfile.

Answer (score -1):

If your file content does look like:

```
/en/family/bitstream/ambiance-bt
/en/family/zxcvbn/bernhard-fashion
/en/family/qwerty/century-751
/en/family/abcd/century-expanded
/en/family/xyz/charter-bt
/en/fonts/sdfsd/dsfsdfs
```

Use below sed expression to get expected output:

```
sed  's/\/en\/family\/\*.*/\/en\/family/' yourfilename
```

To make changes permanent in yourfilename use below sed expression

```
sed -i 's/\/en\/family\/*.*/\/en\/family/' yourfilename
```

Comment: Why use '\*.\*' within pattern regular expression ? '*' is enough no ?

Comment: if you use "*" then it will not going to  replace entire line from "/en/family" it will give you output /en/familybitstream/ambiance-bt
which is not expected according to question.

Comment: yes sorry '.*' is necessary. But your command is wrong, you match nothing with it. Try it. It's because of your '\*' before '.*'. Use of '/' to separate field of substitution command is a bad idea when text to replace contain '/' too. This makes command unreadable and causes some mistake such as your error

Comment: I tried your sed expression but didn't give the desired result.